# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, date, split

Using JavaScript to split a date and rearrange the format.

Date is provided through a json feed as YYYY-MM-DD.

To get the date, I do:

```
var og_date = (v.report[totalItems -1].inspection_date);
console.log(og_date);
```

console log correctly shows the date, ie "2012-10-01".

Next, I try to split the date, for example:

```
console.log(og_date.value.split('-'));
```

And I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Strings don't have a value property.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your question answers itself ;) If `og_date` contains the date, it's probably a string, so `og_date.value` is undefined.

Simply use `og_date.split('-')` instead of `og_date.value.split('-')`

Comment: OHHHH!! hahaha - okay, I was thinking in my head that I needed to get the value of the variable. :) thanks!

Comment: if i need to split one value from whole of object?

Answer (score 4):

`ogdate` is itself a string, why are you trying to access it's `value` property that it doesn't have ?

```
console.log(og_date.split('-'));
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K73zV/)

Answer (score 2):

```
og_date = "2012-10-01";
console.log(og_date); // => "2012-10-01"

console.log(og_date.split('-')); // => [ '2012', '10', '01' ]
```

`og_date.value` would only work if the date were stored as a *property* on the og_date object.
Such as: `var og_date = {}; og_date.value="2012-10-01";`
In that case, your original console.log would work.