# Angular: problem with using Input and Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn some basic concepts of Angular and bumped into a issue that cannot get it solved.

I am using pipe to Capitalize first character of People full name...

but not sure the it always show error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Here is my code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtg4ih

pipe.ts:

```
 export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(nhapTen: string): string {
    console.log(typeof nhapTen);console.log(nhapTen);
      var arr = nhapTen.split(" ");console.log(arr);
       var result;  
     arr.forEach((x) => {
        result += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.substr(1) + " ";
     });
         console.log(typeof result);
      return result;
```

template file:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="nhapTen">: {{nhapTen| capitalize}}

    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Good day,
[look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210445/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined)
Did this resolve your error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable which is undefined. Add Validation,
so you will transform the input only if it has valid value else you will return.

Also Intialize result before you use

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'capitalize'
})
export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(nhapTen: string): string {
    console.log(nhapTen);
     if(!nhapTen){
       return "";
     }
      var arr = nhapTen.split(" ");console.log(arr);
       var result="";   
     arr.forEach((x) => {
        result += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.substr(1) + " ";
     });
         console.log("Result " + result);
      return result;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code sample by first initializing the 'result' variable as an empty string and checked whether the **nhapTen** has a value or not before calling the split function and it did work.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'capitalize'
})
export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(nhapTen: string): string {
      var arr = nhapTen ? nhapTen.split(" ") : [];
      var result = '';  
      arr.forEach((x) => {
        result += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.substr(1) + " ";
      });
      return result;
  }
}
```